# Send multiple file inputs to the server without a form

Tags: ajax, image, flask

With a form and the following input tag:

```
<input type="file" name="images" multiple="" class="inputFileHidden">
```

I can get the file images on my server just by simply searching through the `request.files` object:

`images = request.files.getlist('images')` // returns list of imgs.

In my case, I'm not working with a form, but rather I post it using AJAX.

With simple things like `text` I can easily post it as such:

**Client side**

```
    const i_post_title = document.getElementsByName('post_title')[0];
 
    ....
    
    $.post('/_upload_post', {
        title_post: i_post_title.value
    }).done(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('fail')
    })
```

And receive it on my server by accessing the `request.form` object and passing in the key of the payload sent from the client:

**Server Side**

```
title_post = request.form['title_post']
```

But with files, how should I handle it without having a form?

Comment: Are you looking for that? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Request.args

Comment: If there is no form, where is the file data coming from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Comment: @keanu please rethink your question, the file data is coming from the html input tag `an input field where the user can enter data.`

Comment: @Musa that doesn't answer my question. I've fixed the problem though, using `FormData` and some tweaking when handling `File` js objects.